# In canvas image change marker svg after click button

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, google-maps-markers

I have a canvas image and I have add a marker in it. The marker is a svg type. then when i click a button i want to change the svg into another svg. how do i do it?

It works. Now I want to click on the input and say at function changesvg(), to replace the old svg with new svg at same position. Any ideas? thanks.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Map sprite
var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = "http://www.retrogameguide.com/images/screenshots/snes-legend-of-zelda-link-to-the-past-8.jpg";

var Marker = function() {
  this.Sprite = new Image();
  this.Sprite.src = "/images/1.svg"
  this.Width = 12;
  this.Height = 20;
  this.XPos = 0;
  this.YPos = 0;
}

var Markers = new Array();

var mouseClicked = function(mouse) {
  // Get corrent mouse coords
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseXPos = (mouse.x - rect.left);
  var mouseYPos = (mouse.y - rect.top);

  console.log("Marker added");

  // Move the marker when placed to a better location
  var marker = new Marker();
  marker.XPos = mouseXPos - (marker.Width / 2);
  marker.YPos = mouseYPos - marker.Height;

  Markers.push(marker);
}

// Add mouse click event listener to canvas
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClicked, false);

var firstLoad = function() {
  context.font = "15px Georgia";
  context.textAlign = "center";
}

firstLoad();

var main = function() {
  draw();
};

var draw = function() {
  // Clear Canvas
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw map
  // Sprite, X location, Y location, Image width, Image height
  // You can leave the image height and width off, if you do it will draw the image at default size
  context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, 700, 700);

  // Draw markers
  for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
    var tempMarker = Markers[i];
    // Draw marker
    context.drawImage(tempMarker.Sprite, tempMarker.XPos, tempMarker.YPos, tempMarker.Width, tempMarker.Height);

    // Calculate postion text
    var markerText = "Postion (X:" + tempMarker.XPos + ", Y:" + tempMarker.YPos;

    // Draw a simple box so you can see the position
    var textMeasurements = context.measureText(markerText);
    context.fillStyle = "#666";
    context.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    context.fillRect(tempMarker.XPos - (textMeasurements.width / 2), tempMarker.YPos - 15, textMeasurements.width, 20);
    context.globalAlpha = 1;

    // Draw position above
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillText(markerText, tempMarker.XPos, tempMarker.YPos);
  }
};

function changesvg(){
 var marker = new Marker();
marker.src="/image/2.svg"
context.clearRect(0,0,width,heigth);
context.drawImage(marker, 0, 0, 20, 20);};

setInterval(main, (1000 / 60));
// Refresh 60 times a second
```

```html
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="changesvg();" />

<canvas id="Canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
```

Comment: What SVG are you talking about? Only two images I see your code referring to, are PNGs.

Comment: And the code gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: changesvg is not defined`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wrote svg, but it was png; is important change the this.Sprite.src.
I didn't write the function changesvg(), because I try something, but doesn't work.

Comment: If the question/issue has nothing to do with SVG you should at least remove the SVG tag from the question.

Comment: I have correct the code added svg. Now, i would like change the 1.svg with 2.svg after click. Any idea?